# getting error while performing data augmentation whien i try to import image_to_array in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

ImportError: cannot import name 'image_to_array' from 'keras.preprocessing.image' (C:\Users\shkatta\New folder\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py)
 i am not able to import the above error when i am importing image_to array in keras
please help

Comment: Try `img_to_array` instead

Comment: You are welcome ^^